# How to install snap on Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: snap, amazon-linux

I'm trying to figure out who to install snap so that I can install snap packages like LXD and wifi-ap etc.  snap doesn't appear to be in the base repository and amazon linux 2023 doesn't seem to have a EPEL repository.

```
sudo yum install snapd
    Error: Unable to find a match: snapd

sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
    sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found

sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
    Error: Unable to find a match: amazon-linux-extras
```

Comment: Why do you want run wifi on an AWS VM?

Comment: I've exported a  Amazon Linux 2023 instance to ova then imported it into a VMWare instance where I'm using USB pass-through.

Answer (score 0):

After failing to find any official solution I decided to download the snapd packages from EPEL-9 and install them manually on my Amazon Linux 2023 box.

There was one error regarding selinux which meant I had to disable selinix to allow snapd to run.   I'm sure it wouldn't take much work to figure out a more security friendly fix.

With snapd install I then did 'snap install lxd' which worked and then after 'lxd init --auto' I created my first LXD instance on Amazon Linux 2023.

I intend to revisit this question when in the near future I do a formal install process and can hopefully give more detail.